# How to do this mysql query where I want to query columns side by side?

Tags: python, mysql

I've my table structure like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
 1    1    1
 1    2    1
 1    3    1
 2    10   1
```

Now I have information like this in tuples in python `(1,2)` for column 1 and `(1,1)` for column 3.

I want to query the table such that in the select clause I want to correspond column 1 value with column 3.

By that I mean

There will be two queries:

```
Select * from table where col1 = 1 and col3 = 1;
Select * from table where col1 = 2 and col3 = 1;
```

I want to combine these and do this for as many entries as I have in my tuples.
I can do lots of ands and union but that is not a good solution beyond 10 values.

Comment: Why not a for loop in python?

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest method, that's not likely to result in performance problems, is going to be iterating across the tuples and generating an AND condition for each, enclosed in parentheses and joined by OR conditions, to produce a query thus:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (col1 = 1 AND col3 = 1) 
  OR  (col1 = 2 AND col3 = 1) 
  OR  (...)
```

You're right, though, in that that likely won't scale particularly well. You might instead first analyze the tuples whose values you're using in the WHERE clause, in order to generate a somewhat more compact condition which, for each unique acceptable col1 value, OR's together all acceptable col3 values, and then ANDs them against the col1 value. For example, consider the tuples `(1, 1)`, `(1, 2)`, `(2, 1)`, `(2, 3)`, and the following query generated from them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (col1 = 1 AND (col3 = 1 OR col3 = 2)) 
  OR  (col1 = 2 AND (col3 = 1 OR col3 = 3))
```

That's a bit less messy than the result of the first method, and requires a fair bit more effort ahead of time, but it's probably going to execute significantly faster, because AND short-circuiting means the database engine can more quickly determine whether a given row will satisfy the WHERE clause; instead of needing to check each `(col1 = @m AND col2 = @n)` condition individually for every row, it can simply check whether the row's col1 value matches, and ignore the rest of the condition if it doesn't.

(Of course, MySQL's query optimizer should already be doing this for you, and while it'd take thorough benchmarking to be certain, given the obviousness of the optimization I suspect very strongly that you're getting this for free. The second form of the query is still more human-readable, though, which may or may not matter to you.)

Anyway, if you need to do this across many tuples of acceptable values, you're going to be generating either one relatively complex query, or a bunch of simple-minded ones; each approach has benefits and drawbacks, but given your requirements and your input, I tend to doubt you're going to find an algorithm which generates a query that's both significantly more compact, and still readable enough to debug should it misbehave.

If you're concerned about performance, I'd suggest waiting to worry about that until you've demonstrated that a performance problem exists. If you already have done that, check the indexes on the table you're querying; if you haven't created an index across the columns you're using in your WHERE condition, now would be an excellent time to do so.